# Force Silverlight 4 client install, NOT Silverlight 5

Tags: silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I would like my application to download and install Silverlight 4, NOT Silverlight 5. Anyone

SL v.4+ installed on client computer = my app runs perfect.
SL v.5+ installed on client computer = my app runs like poop and crashes.

This is a business application where I can tell the client what version to install. The problem is, with the following standard markup generated by VS2010, it forces SL5 to install each time.

Is there a way to make SL 4 to install, since there are clearly bugs in compatibility regarding the version of SL installed the client (v4 and v5).

Re-writing SL code is not an option.

Any help would be great.. here's the markup auto-generated by VS.

Thanks.

```
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server" style="height:100%">
    <div id="silverlightControlHost">
        <object data="data:application/x-silverlight-2," type="application/x-silverlight-2" width="100%" height="100%">
          <param name="source" value="ClientBin/Web.Portal.xap"/>
          <param name="onError" value="onSilverlightError" />
          <param name="background" value="white" />
          <param name="minRuntimeVersion" value="4.0.60310.0" />
          <param name="autoUpgrade" value="true" />
          <a href="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=149156&v=4.0.60310.0" style="text-decoration:none">
              <img src="http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=161376" alt="Get Microsoft Silverlight" style="border-style:none"/>
          </a>
        </object><iframe id="_sl_historyFrame" style="visibility:hidden;height:0px;width:0px;border:0px"></iframe></div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The contents of the `<object>` element (minus the `<param>`s) are displayed in the user's browser if they don't have the Silverlight plugin, or their version is too old.  You can change this content to be whatever you want.  In particular, you could change it so that it takes you to a page where you can download the Silverlight 4 plugin instead of the official Microsoft Silverlight page.

I couldn't find anywhere to download the installer for the Silverlight 4 on the Microsoft website.  However, if you happen to have a copy of the this installer lying around somewhere, you could try uploading that to your website and linking to it.

Comment: This is exactly what I ended up doing.